# var dataString = \'search=\'+ searchid; - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I am trying to understand a bit of code to be able to apply a similar concept in my coursework.

```
$(function(){
    $(".search").keyup(function() {
        var searchid = $(this).val();
        var dataString = \'search=\'+ searchid;
        if(searchid!=\'\') {
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

What is the dataString variable trying to do?

Comment: Is this code output by another script or server-side language? It looks like the whole code might be written as a text literal somewhere - and if that’s the case, and single quotes are used as the string delimiter, then the single quotes inside of it would need to be escaped that way of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few things that seem "off" with this snippet of code, which I'll address below.

**What is this code doing?**

It looks like some basic functionality that might be used to build a search querystring that is passed onto some AJAX request that will search for something on the server.

Basically, you'll want to build a string that looks like `search={your-search-term}`, which when posted to the server, the search term `{your-search-term}` can be easily identified and used to search.

**Noted Code Issues**

As mentioned, there are a few issues that you might want to consider changing:

- **The Use of Escaped Quotes (i.e. `\'`)** - You really don't need to escape these as they aren't present within an existing string. Since you are just building a string, simply replace them with a normal `'` instead. Without knowing more about your complete scenario, it's difficult to advise further on this.
- **Checking String Length** - Your existing code once again checks if the `searchId` is an empty string, however you may want to consider checking the length to see if it actually empty via `searchId.length != 0`, you could also trim this as well (i.e. `searchId.trim().length != 0`).
- **Consider A Delay (Optional)** - At present, your current code will be executed every time a key is pressed, which can be good (or bad) depending on your needs. If you are going to be hitting the server, you may consider adding a delay to your code to ensure the user has stopped typing before hitting the server.

You can see some of these changes implemented below in the annotated code snippet:

```
// This is a startup function that will execute when everything is loaded
$(function () {
    // When a keyup event is triggered in your "search" element...
    $(".search").keyup(function () {
        // Grab the contents of the search box
        var searchId = $(this).val();
        // Build a data string (i.e. string=searchTerm), you didn't previously need the
        // escaping slashes
        var dataString = 'search=' + searchId;
        // Now check if actually have a search term (you may prefer to check the length
        // to ensure it is actually empty)
        if(searchId.length != 0) {
             // There is a search, so do something here
        }
    }
}
```